# Installing jdk7u7 on Centos5.8

Tags: linux, centos, java, installation, rpm

I'm trying to install Java SDK (jdk-7u7-linux-i586.rpm) on Linux CentosOS 5.8.

Im using [this guide](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-sun-oracle-java-jdk-jre-7-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/), and downloading everything from the Oracle website.

When executing `rpm -Uvh /path/to/binary/jdk-7u7-linux-i586.rpm` the package is installing java:

```
[root@ip-***-***-**-189 java]# rpm -Uvh jdk-7u7-linux-i586.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:jdk                    ########################################### [100%]
```

But after it finishes I get these errors:

```
Unpacking JAR files...
        rt.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/rt.pack
        jsse.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/jsse.pack
        charsets.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/charsets.pack
        tools.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/tools.pack
        localedata.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/ext/localedata.pack
        plugin.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/plugin.pack
        javaws.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/javaws.pack
        deploy.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/deploy.pack
```

Though it seems like everything is installed right, as I do these checks:

```
[root@ip-***-***-**-189 java]# java -version
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)

[root@ip-***-***-**-189 java]# javac -version
javac 1.7.0_07

[root@ip-***-***-**-189 java]# javaws
Java(TM) Web Start 10.7.0.10-fcs
```

I would still like to know:

- What are these errors ?
- Are they critical for running `.jar` files (I
  need to use Selenium on the server) ?
- How can I install without these
  errors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw the same error, but on a manual inspection, the jar files were present and appeared to have been deployed properly. I believe it's safe to ignore the errors. Though, if there's yet another update out, I guess we're updating again...

Answer (score 1):

I got the same errors. Ignore them and update to **7u9**.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Ward I see no big difference to Michaels answer. Apart from that I know that there is a more recent version out, which does not contain that errors (and has some severe security fixes). I see no reason to debug Oracles broken RPMs. They were not able to provide a proper jexec-init-script a very long time, too.